# I'm trying to create and html page as a body for an email. How do I pass it into my setBody() using yiiMail?

Tags: php, html, email, yii

I have a .php page with the following code:

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
    Hi <?php echo $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name']?>,
    <br><br>
    To reset your password, please go to the following page:
    <br>
    <?php 
            $url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('user/reset/id/'.  $key);
            echo "<a href='{$url}'>{$url}</a>";
    ?>
    <br>
    Your password will be automatically reset, and a new password will be emailed to you.        
</body>
```

I want to be able to put this inside a function I created in the Controller inside setBody() here:

```
  public function emailAll($url)
    {

        $this->set_mail_settings();
        $message = new YiiMailMessage;        

            $emails = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT group_concat(email) as em FROM persons WHERE party_id != 184")->queryRow();
            $email_ids = explode(",",$emails["em"]);
            $message->setBcc($email_ids);
            $message->setBody('To view, click here: '.$url);
            $message->subject = 'New Announcement Posted!';
            $message->addTo('dcp@gmail.com');
            $message->from = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
            Yii::app()->mail->send($message);                      
    }
```

The URL link that I want inside the body is coded from the actionCreate() which is here:

```
 $currentid = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select id from content where id = (select max(id) from content)")->queryRow();
                Yii::app()->session['announcement_message'] = 'You have successfully created an announcement.';

                $url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('announcement/view/id/'.  $currentid["id"]);

                $this->emailAll($url);

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
```

I'm just now trying to figure out how I would send that .php page that has html inside into the setBody() along with $url I passed. Any help?

Comment: do you want to set in emailAll function? It's sending mail to more than one user. Are you sure your sending reset password mail to thiose users?

Comment: I'm sorry the body mail was just an example. I'm supposed to be sending a link to the most recent announcement, not the reset password. I posted the wrong code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you store the mail template .php file as a view in your corresponding view folder, then call

```
$message->setBody(
    $this->renderPartial("_yourTemplateFileName",
             array("key"=>$key,'user'=>$user),true,false)
 );
```

RenderPartial can process a file and return the output by setting the third parameter return as true, the fourth parameter is for processing Js stuff not required in this context.